# There are 3 workers in a company that has 5 working days in a week.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are 3 workers in a company that has 5 working days in a week.In how many ways can the 3 workers take leave/rest if no two workers can take leave on the same day.

**Attempt:** The first worker can take leave on Monday, and that gives 8 ways by which the other two workers can take a leave till Friday. The first worker can take a leave on Tue which gives another 8 ways for others to take a leave. If the first worker takes a leave on Wed, it gives 2 ways for the remaining 2 workers to take a leave till friday. So this gives us 8+8+2=18 ways. Don't know how to go ahead.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: The first worker can take leave on Monday, and that gives 8 ways by which the other two workers can take a leave till Friday. The first worker can take a leave on Tue which gives another 8 ways for others to take a leave. If the first worker takes a leave on Wed, it gives 2 ways for the remaining 2 workers to take a leave till friday. So this gives us 8+8+2=18 ways. Don't know how to go ahead..

Comment: Go ahead with what? You have your answer, right?

Comment: No, but the first leave (on monday) could also be taken by worker no.2 and this would give us similar results. And then it could also be taken by worker no. 3. This is a long and winding way...I was looking to apply some formula to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1st worker can take leave on any of 5 days.

The 2nd can take leave on any of remaining 4 days.

The 3rd now has only 3 choices

Thus the number of ways = $5\cdot4\cdot3$ = 60.

You can instead also use the permutation *formula*, $^5P_3$ = 60

*PS*: The above assumes that each worker takes leave for only 1 day in the week.

If no restrictions are there, each day one of the 3 workers (or none) can take leave, so there are 4 choices for each day, and # of possible ways = $4^5$ = 1024

So much leeway is quite impractical, but the question hasn't clearly spelt out what is permissible.

Comment: Makes sense.Thanks.

Comment: Why the downvote ?

Comment: I gave an upvote

Comment: @trueblueanil I wasn't the downvoter, but I think it has been downvoted because it is generally discouraged to spoil the answer to a homework problem before the OP has done something himself. I just did +1.

Comment: @Jason You can't upvote yet, but you can accept the answer by clicking the green mark.

Comment: @wythagoras: Thanks, I saw he had made some attempts. Any way....

Comment: @trueblueanil I missed the comments. I edited the attempt in the comment in the question to avoid it form being deleted, closed or downvoted.

Comment: This assumes that each worker will take exactly one day off. That's a limitation not specified in the question.

Comment: @chirlu: That is a good catch (+1). I will add a PS